# Accessing Hash of hash of Array in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, hashtable

I have the following data I wish to access:

```
$data1=   
{'Family' => {
    'House' => [
        {
            'Id' => '1111',
            'Name' => 'DFG'
        },
        {
            'Id' => '211',
            'Name' => 'ABC'
        }
               ]
            }
}
```

I want to access the each Name field value. I am using this code:

```
foreach(keys%$data1) {

    if(ref($data1->{$_}) eq 'HASH') {

        foreach my $inner_key (keys%{$data1->{$_}})    {

            print "Key:$inner_key and value:$data1->{$_}->{$inner_key}\n";   
        }
    } 
    else {

            print "Key: $_ and Value: $data1->{$_}\n"
    } 
}
```

It prints `Key:House and value:ARRAY(OXXX)`.

I know I am doing something wrong. Since the data in 'House' is an array of hashes, I even tried accessing through  `$data1->{$_}->{$inner_key}[0]`. What is wrong in the code???

Comment: You seem to have a hash with a hash of an array of hashes (?! am I seeing that right?) so something like: `for $inner_hash (@{ $data1->{Family}{House} }) { say "Name: $innerhash->{Name}" }` is needed to get inside (*a.k.a*. "dereference") the array.

Comment: As a side note, this data structure is wasting all the benefits of hashes, and you might just replace it all with arrays without losing any functionality. Consider `$data1->{Family}{House}{1111} = "DFG"` assuming your IDs or names are unique.

Answer (score 3):

You have to dereference array for foreach loop first, and then dereference hashref to reach "Name" values.

```
print "Key:$inner_key and value:$_->{Name}\n" 
  for @{$data1->{$_}->{$inner_key}};
```

Comment: I should've pressed reload. My answer nearly duplicates yours.  Removing it.

Comment: Actually I'll leave it and add "for further reference" material and not that it should not be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) first to learn how to create and use references.

Here is a demonstration:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data1=   
{'Family' => {
        'House' => [
        {
            'Id' => '1111',
            'Name' => 'DFG'
        },
        {
            'Id' => '211',
            'Name' => 'ABC'
        }
        ]
    }
};

while (my ($key1, $val1) = each %$data1) {
    print "\$key1 = $key1\n";
    while (my ($key2, $val2) = each %$val1) {
        print "\t\$key2 = $key2\n";
        foreach my $val3 (@$val2) {
            while (my ($key4, $val4) = each %$val3) {
                print "\t\t\$key4 = $key4 => $val4\n";
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[**Edit** I typed too slowly while answering, so this response bascially duplicates @mpapec's below - I will leave the references here and you can vote me up for those ;-)  but **do not** accept my response as the answer].

---

Try something like the following to see if it works:

```
for $inner_hash (@{ $data1->{Family}{House} }) { 
   say "Name: $inner_hash->{Name}" 
   }
```

since you need to get the inner hashes' values from inside the elements of the array (that is what `value:ARRAY(OXXX)` is telling you).

You can use `perldoc` to look at the [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html), [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) **PODs** to learn more about data structures and dereferencing. If keeping your data structure in mind while you are writing code  gets to be too hard to do, it may mean you need to simplify things: either the data itself or by writing `sub`'s to make it easier to access, or making `use` some of the excellent utility modules from CPAN.

There's also some good perl data structure related tutorials out there. The POD/perldoc documentation that ships with perl (along with Chapter 9 of [Programming Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004923)) is the canonical reference, but you might browse these nodes from perlmonks:

- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=references%20quick%20reference)
- [Referencing in advanced data structures](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Referencing%20in%20advanced%20data%20structures)
- [Visualizing perl data structures](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=481745)
- [Perlmonks Hash Tutorial](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=90610)

**NB** Above I'm using the `perlcritic` and [Perl Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596001738) style of dereferencing: *e.g.:* `@{ $data1->{Family}{House} }` so the syntax reminds me that the inner hashes (or inner-**inner**?) are inside an array.  There's a cool new way of dereferencing being introduced in perl 5.20 called [postfix dereferencing](http://perltricks.com/article/68/2014/2/13/Cool-new-Perl-feature-postfix-dereferencing) which will be great, but you can't go wrong following the recommendations of **PBP**.

"Until you start thinking in terms of hashes, you aren't really thinking in Perl."  -- Larry Wall

Cheers,

Comment: You forgot the underscore in your `$innerhash` but +1 for the links.

Comment: fixed it thanks - I was trying to use the PBP policies for choosing variable names. Otherwise, I would've called it $ihsh :-) –